# If value is true, show form

Tags: javascript

I have a form that I've built out and I am stuck on a bug that I am trying to resolve. I can't seem to figure out what's causing it.

The video below shows that when `states.includes(resident.value)` is `false`, that it hides the form by settings a `display: none` attribute and then removing it if it is true.

I have a `console.log(states.includes(resident.value));` showing if the response value is in the array.

[image]

---

**Problem**:

When I submit the form, it redirects to a success page and when I click the back button, it lands back on the 'California' drop-down but the form is not shown because `states.includes(resident.value)` is `false` (shown below) until the drop-down is clicked on the California option again:

[image]

**Code**:

```
var contactFormID = document.getElementById('contactForm');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    formHandler();
});

function formHandler() {
    contactFormID.style.display = 'block';

    if (resident == null) return;

    if (!states.includes(resident.value))
        contactFormID.style.display = 'none';

    console.log(states.includes(resident.value));

    resident.addEventListener('change', formHandler);
}

<div class="row mt-5 resident">
    <div class="col-md">
        <label for="resident">I am a resident of:</label>
        <select class="custom-select" id="resident" required>
            <option value="" hidden selected>Choose...</option>
            <?php foreach (Vars::states() as $state): ?>
                <option value="<?= $state['key']; ?>"><?= $state['name']; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Select state of residence.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<form class="needs-validation <?= $form->submitted(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-states="<?= Vars::enabled_states_as_string(); ?>" novalidate>
"All the good input content"
</form>
```

Comment: you could use the [history api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) to store a viariable and use it if the back button is pushed

Comment: Try this localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');var cat = localStorage.getItem('myCat');https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a suspicion that this might be a browser issue but since I don't have the full source I haven't tested in any other browsers on any other OSes. That said, the easiest solution to this problem is probably to dispatch a change event to your select before you perform the test (assuming that you've also confirmed that `resident.value` does indeed hold the value for California):

```
resident.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

This will basically programmatically simulate what you are already doing when you reselect California in your second video. If `resident.value` does NOT hold the correct value then you will need another solution like `localStorage`.

Comment: Unfortunately, when the drop down is changed it holds a value of 'true', but if I click the back button and it lands on California, it shows 'false'. @Ashley

Comment: Would I set the localStorage within the function? I've never used localStorage before.

Comment: `states.includes(resident.value)` is false, but trigerring the change event in my solution above before performing the `states.includes(resident.value)` test may change that.

Answer (score 0):

you can save resident value in sessionStorage. it will be cleared when window will be closed.
here is working code which use sessionStorage:

```
var states = ["ws"];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    formHandler(null, sessionStorage.getItem('contactForm_resident'));
    const resident = document.getElementById('resident');
    resident.addEventListener('change', formHandler);
});

function formHandler(event, value) {
    const contactFormID = document.getElementById('contactForm');
    const resident = document.getElementById('resident');


    if (resident == null) return;
    if (value) resident.value = value;

    if (!states.includes(resident.value))
        contactFormID.style.display = 'none';
    else 
        contactFormID.style.display = 'block';
    sessionStorage.setItem('contactForm_resident', resident.value);
    console.log(states.includes(resident.value));
}
```

try it here - [working code fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cheaterr/rodeukp7/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my 2 cents :) The problem is that the array isn't loaded until you click on the form field load the array by using window.onload() it takes a callback that runs on page load. so you can do something like this:

```
window.onload(()=> {
  var field = document.getElementById('resident')
  var isResident = states.includes(_field.value)
  if(isResident && isResident !== undefined){
    //do something
  } else {
    //do something else
  }
})
```